# IWindsorContainer - when to call Release()

Tags: castle-windsor, dispose

When I have resolved a component using container.Resolve(), and I have finished using it, should I call Release()?

At the moment I call Dispose on any IDisposable that the container has got for me. Should I not call Dispose() on the object, but instead call Release() on the container instead? Does it do the same thing?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

- `Release` what you `Resolve` (explicitly, or implicitly - via typed factory)
- `Dispose` what you create and own. (and you don't own what container creates, so don't dispose it - container will).

Long answer: [I wrote a blogpost going into more details](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/)

[The documentation on lifestyles goes into more depth as well](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md)

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof. I know you RTFM comment was in jest, but this page http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/manual/windsortypedocs/Generated_IWindsorContainer.html just says 'Releases the component instance'!! The API docs could be a little more forthcoming. But thank you for your answer!